# Anomaly in the Plot Function

Tags: plotting

I was trying to plot a simple function `Plot[Cos[2 Pi 1.46 x/1.3], {x, 0, 50}]`. But found out there is a weird anomaly in the result as shown in the attached image.[image] As you can see in the image, there is a weird discontinuous jump of the simple Cosine function. Can anyone explain what is happening here?

Comment: Not enough `PlotPoints`. Try a higher setting like `PlotPoints -> 35` and report back.

Comment: Problem solved. At `PlotPoints->50` there is still discontinuity, at `PlotPoints -> 100`, the curve is smooth. Thank you J.M.

Comment: To remove plot anomalies you should also try increasing `MaxRecursion`